# How to make TeamCity %build.number% change following dependency change trigger?

Tags: c#, teamcity, version, versioning, teamcity-8.0

The Assembly Patcher Build Feature in all our build configurations is set to use `0.0.%build.counter%.%build.vcs.number%` as the version number.

On our TeamCity servers, builds triggered by "VCS changes" (i.e. trigger a build on each check-in) set the correct version number in the project's `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

Problem is, builds triggered by "Artifact Dependency changes" do not set the correct version number in the project's `AssemblyInfo.cs`. In fact, these builds set the `AssemblyInfo.cs` version number to be the `0.0.%build.counter%.%build.vcs.number%` of the most recent "VCS changes" Triggered build.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the IntelliSense if you start typing `%dep.` you'll be able to choose between several self-explanatory options. For example:

```
%dep.yourSourceBuild.build.number%
```